# 500 Internal Server Error, Images not loading

Tags: image, apache

My website bit.ly/1c03DMD

I am facing issue of

> Internal Server Error 
>   The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request. 
>   Please contact the server administrator and inform them of the time
>   the error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this
>   error. 
>   More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log. 
>   Apache Server at bit.ly/1c03DMD Port 80

The website is loading properly but the images are not loading. When I try to click on any image it shows 500: Internal Server Error.

I have discussed this with my hosting support but they are saying that there is some issue in our website, their hosting is working properly.

Nothing has been modified in the website. Website was working fine few days back when suddenly I am seeing this error.

Here is the log file from Apache Logs:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qg74y19sd1az1kh/ex20131123000001-182.50.130.30.log
From Error Logs. https://dropbox.com/s/bkc2aomvrdsom88/2f3dcf12-error.log

I have already googled a lot regarding it but could not find the correct solution. 
Can any one help me in resolving this.
Thankyou in advance

Comment: "More information about this error may be available in the server error log."

Comment: This might be caused by a configuration change by the web hosting company, which disallows certain settings to be made in an `.htaccess` file. What does the server error log state about the error?

Comment: Thankyou for reply.
Here is the log file https://www.dropbox.com/s/qg74y19sd1az1kh/ex20131123000001-182.50.130.30.log

Comment: To update the previous log was from Apache Logs. Here is a new one from Error Logs. https://www.dropbox.com/s/bkc2aomvrdsom88/2f3dcf12-error.log

Comment: Please provide the logs in-line.  Nobody is going to download your mystery files.

Answer (score 4):

Main reason of this error is mess with .htaccess file in root directoy. You may try the following to resolve this:

1)Now open .htaccess file and delete all lines then update the file.Now you have a fresh new file.Now your site should open again. Next refresh your permalink settings or you may get 404 error while open any post.

You can also do this by rename the .htaccess file like .htaccess_old.Then don’t forget to refresh your permalink settings.

First backup the .htaccess file then perform the above step.

Comment: Try to increase PHP Memory Limit @user3024845

Comment: Did the .htaccess step but no results.

Also tried the memory limit increase and not working. I reverted everything back to original state.

Comment: Take the original .htaccess file, and comment out (with # ) all lines. See if your site is no longer getting the 500 error. That would show that the problem is in the .htaccess. Uncomment sections one at a time until you find the offending party (you will need to understand .htaccess commands, to do this). One common cause of 500 errors is the use of php_value or php_flag commands, which belong in a php.ini file. Many hosts are now banning "Options" commands too.

Answer (score 0):

nazim10's answer seemed to help me. stack-overflow says I need 50 reputation to post a comment, so I'm posting instead. I had this in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Deny from all
<Files ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|pdf|txt|bmp)$">
   order deny, allow
   allow from all
</Files>
ErrorDocument 403 /error/404.php
</IfModule>
```

and needed to change `order deny, allow` to `order deny,allow`
a simple space after a `,` in .htaccess can break things.